# What is the actual meaning of the AWS S3 Last Modified Date attribute?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

The AWS [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/UsingMetadata.html) defines the Last Modified attribute of an S3 object as "Object creation date or the last modified date, whichever is the latest." but I was wondering how is this date actually calculated. Is it the upload start time or does it coincide with the actual upload end time, once the object is visible on S3.

To provide some context on what I am trying to do:
I am trying to fetch the list of all new files uploaded in an S3 bucket periodically, for example, every day, say at 8:00AM I want to get all the files that were uploaded since the day before at the same time, but I am worried that I might miss a file if it is uploaded moments before 8:00AM and is not yet visible until after 8:00AM. This is why I need to know how this attribute works.

Before suggesting using S3 Events and AWS Lamda functions, or naming conventions on the files, the S3 bucket is in another AWS account and I have no control over how files are named, triggers, etc.

Thanks to anyone who can help!

Comment: Assuming you run sometime after 8:00, you'll still get the file, even if the last modified date happens when the file starts upload.  Further, even if you miss it, you'll catch it the next day.  Really, though, you should keep a list of files you've seen with their metadata, and transfer any that don't match what you expect.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I think if the upload starts at 7:59 and ends at 8:05, and if the last modified attribute is 7:59, when it runs the next day I would miss it because I am looking for all files with the attribute from 8 to 8. With this being said, keeping a list of already processed files seems like the best approach to me so far.

Comment: Or you could simply tag each object when you process it, and the todo list becomes "objects that don't have the processed tag".

Comment: @jarmond Metadata tags in S3 are immutable with the objects, whe you tag an object you are actually overwriting the same object but with the new metadata (reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/add-object-metadata.html). The S3 bucket in question is in another AWS account and I only have read access. Plus, even if I had write access, I would end up changing the last modified field this way.